# unable to deploy EFK stack on kubernetes (using kubespray)

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, kubespray, efk

i'm trying to deploy EFK stack on production kubernetes cluster (installed using kubespray), we have 3 nodes, 1 master + 2 workers, i need to use elasticsearch as a statefulset and use a local folder in master node to store logs (local storage for persistance), my configuration is :

```
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kube-logging

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      name: rest
    - port: 9300
      name: inter-node
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
  namespace: kube-logging
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-pv
  namespace: kube-logging
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /tmp/elastic
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
  namespace: kube-logging
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 2Gi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: local-storage
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
---
```

so this was my configuration but when it's applied, one of the two pods for Elasticsearch still  in pending status.
when i did kubectl describe for this pod this is the error that i get:
"1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind"

is my configuration correct ? must i use PV + storageclass + volumeClaimTemplates ?
thank you in advance.

Those are my outputs:

```
    [root@node1 nex]# kubectl get pv
NAME    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                            STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
my-pv   5Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    kube-logging/data-es-cluster-0   local-storage            24m
[root@node1 nex]# kubectl get pvc
NAME                STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS    AGE
data-es-cluster-0   Bound     my-pv    5Gi        RWO            local-storage   24m
data-es-cluster-1   Pending                                      local-storage   23m
[root@node1 nex]# kubectl describe pvc data-es-cluster-0
Name:          data-es-cluster-0
Namespace:     kube-logging
StorageClass:  local-storage
Status:        Bound
Volume:        my-pv
Labels:        app=elasticsearch
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      5Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    es-cluster-0
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                         -------
  Normal  WaitForFirstConsumer  24m   persistentvolume-controller  waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
[root@node1 nex]# kubectl describe pvc data-es-cluster-1
Name:          data-es-cluster-1
Namespace:     kube-logging
StorageClass:  local-storage
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app=elasticsearch
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    es-cluster-1
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                   From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----                  ----                         -------
  Normal  WaitForFirstConsumer  4m12s (x82 over 24m)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
[root@node1 nex]#
```

Comment: share output of kubectl get pvc, kubectl describe pvc pvcname

Comment: hello @ArghyaSadhu i edited my question by adding the outputs as requested, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is my configuration correct ? must i use PV + storageclass +
>   volumeClaimTemplates ? thank you in advance.

Apart from what @Arghya Sadhu already suggested in his answer, I'd like to highlight one more thing in your current setup.

If you're ok with the fact that your Elasticsearch `Pods` will be scheduled only on one particular node (in your case your **master node**), you can still use the [local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) volume type. Don't confuse it however with [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath). I noticed in your `PV` definition that you used `hostPath` key so chances are that you're not completely aware of the differences between this two concepts. Although they are quite similar, [local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) type has bigger capabilities and some undeniable advantages over `hostPath`.

As you can read in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local):

> A local volume represents a mounted local storage device such as a
>   disk, partition or directory.

So it means that apart from specific directory you're also able to mount local disk or partition (`/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdb5` etc.). It can be e.g. an **LVM** partition with strictly defined capacity. Keep in mind that when it comes to mounting a local directory you are not able to enforce the capacity that can be actually used, so even if you define let's say `5Gi`, logs can be written to your local directory even if this value is exceeded. But it's not the case with `logical volume` as you're able to define it's capacity and make sure it won't use more disk space than you gave it.

Second difference is that:

> Compared to `hostPath` volumes, `local` volumes can be used in a durable
>   and portable manner without manually scheduling Pods to nodes, as the
>   system is aware of the volume’s node constraints by looking at the
>   node affinity on the PersistentVolume.

In this case it is the `PersistentVolume` where you define your **node affinity**, so any `Pod` (it can be `Pod` managed by your `StatefulSet`) which uses subsequently `local-storage` storage class and corresponding `PersistenVolume` will be automatically scheduled on the right node.

As you can read further, `nodeAffinity` is actually the required field in such `PV`:

> PersistentVolume `nodeAffinity` is required when using local volumes.
>   It enables the Kubernetes scheduler to correctly schedule Pods using
>   local volumes to the correct node.

As far as I understand, your kubernetes cluster is set up locally/on-premise. In this case NFS could be a right choice.

If you used some cloud environment then you could use persistent storage offered by your particular cloud provider e.g. `GCEPersistentDisk` or `AWSElasticBlockStore`. The full list of persistent volume types currently supported by kubernetes you can find [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes).

So again, If you're concerned about node-level redundancy in your `StatefulSet` and you would like your 2 Elasticsearch `Pods` to be scheduled always on different nodes, as @Arghya Sadhu already suggested, use NFS or some other non-local storage.

However if you're not concerned about node-level redundancy and you're totally ok with fact that both your Elasticsearch `Pods` are running on the same node (**master** node in your case), please follow me :)

As @Arghya Sadhu rightly pointed out:

> Even if a PV which is already bound to a PVC have spare capacity it
>   can not be again bound to another PVC because it's one to one mapping
>   between PV and PVC.

Although it's always one to one mapping between `PV` and `PVC`, it doesn't mean you cannot use a single `PVC` in many Pods.

Note, that in your `StatefulSet` example you used `volumeClaimTemplates` which basically means that each time when a new `Pod` managed by your `StatefulSet` is created, also a new corresponding `PersistentVolumeClaim` is created based on this template. So if you have e.g. `10Gi` `PersistentVolume` defined, no matter if you request in your claim all `10Gi` or only half of it, only first `PVC` will be successfully bound to your `PV`.

But instead of using `volumeClaimTemplates` and creating a separate `PVC` for every stateful `Pod` you can make them use a single, manually defined `PVC`. Please take a look at the following example:

First thing we need is a storage class. It looks quite similar to the one in your exaple:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

First difference between this setup and yours is in `PV` definition. Instead of `hostPath` we're using here [local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /var/tmp/test ### path on your master node
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - your-master-node-name
```

Note that apart from defining `local` path, we also defined `nodeAffinity` rule that makes sure that all `Pods` which get this particular `PV` will be automatically scheduled on our **master node**.

Then we have our manually applied `PVC`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage
```

This `PVC` can now be used by all (in your example 2) `Pods` managed by `StatefulSet`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 2 # by default is 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx # has to match .spec.selector.matchLabels
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mypd
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
      - name: mypd
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: myclaim
```

Note that in the above example we don't use `volumeClaimTemplates` any more but a single `PersistentVolumeClaim` which can be used by all our Pods. Pods are still unique as they are managed by a `StatefulSet` but instead of using unique `PVCs`, they use common one. Thanks to this approach both `Pods` can write logs to a single volume at the same time.

In my example I used the nginx server to make the replication as easy as possible for everyone who wants to try it out quickly but I believe you can easily adjust it to your needs.